# Cordova 4.0.0 project add platform issue?

Tags: cordova, xcode5, cordova-3, cordova-4

I update cordova 3.5.0 to 4.0.1 on my system. Then, i create new project. But i can't add platform for that project. I give the following command on Terminal. **cordova platform add ios** . I am getting the following issue.

**Unable to fetch platform ios: Error: No compatible version found: cordova-ios@'>=8458588.0.0-0 <8458589.0.0-0'
Valid install targets:
["3.5.0","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3"]**

Please guide me. Thank You !!!

Comment: What command did you use to update cordova?

Comment: I am using the following command, sudo npm update -g cordova

Answer (score 2):

cordova platform add ios@3.6.3